# Error: function types not truly compatible in ISO C [-Werror=pedantic]

Tags: c, gcc

When I try to compile a C source code, which includes the "sgx-lib.h" header file, using gcc, it pops out following errors:

```
 In file included from src/trusted/service_runtime/nacl_test_injection_main.c:9:0:
src/trusted/service_runtime/opensgx/libsgx/include/sgx-lib.h:94:42: error: function types not truly compatible in ISO C [-Werror=pedantic]
 extern int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
                                          ^
src/trusted/service_runtime/opensgx/libsgx/include/sgx-lib.h:94:42: error: function types not truly compatible in ISO C [-Werror=pedantic]
src/trusted/service_runtime/opensgx/libsgx/include/sgx-lib.h:96:38: error: function types not truly compatible in ISO C [-Werror=pedantic]
 extern int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
                                      ^
src/trusted/service_runtime/opensgx/libsgx/include/sgx-lib.h:96:38: error: function types not truly compatible in ISO C [-Werror=pedantic]
src/trusted/service_runtime/opensgx/libsgx/include/sgx-lib.h:97:45: error: function types not truly compatible in ISO C [-Werror=pedantic]
 extern int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
                                             ^
src/trusted/service_runtime/opensgx/libsgx/include/sgx-lib.h:97:45: error: function types not truly compatible in ISO C [-Werror=pedantic]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

The gcc flags are as follows:

```
'-fPIE', '-m64', '-Wall', '-pedantic', '-Wextra', '-Wno-long-long', '-Wswitch-enum', '-Wsign-compare', '-Wundef', '-fdiagnostics-show-option', '-fvisibility=hidden', '-Werror', '-Wno-variadic-macros', '--param', 'ssp-buffer-size=4', '-O2', '-static', '-fno-stack-protector', '-Isrc/trusted/service_runtime/opensgx/include', '-Isrc/trusted/service_runtime/opensgx/share/include', '-Isrc/trusted/service_runtime/opensgx/libsgx/include', '-fPIC', '-fvisibility=hidden', '-std=gnu11', '-nostdlib'
```

Does anyone know what is the cause of the `error: function types not truly compatible in ISO C [-Werror=pedantic]`?

By the way, if I remove the `-pedantic` flag, everything compiles fine.

Thanks!

Comment: It is pointing to the second argument of each function, only two of which are `const`. The other possibility is that `struct sockaddr` is somehow different between each function definition?

Comment: I think this is what is going on: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2005-02/msg01047.html